# Нужно ли выделить запятыми (как оборот) слова "вот так"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Предложение такое: *«Вот так, на примере истории Ивана Ивановича, автор объяснил читателю свои взгляды»*.

Comment: Исходя из наличия поясняющего местоимения и частицы получается, что нужно обособлять запятыми... Учитель их зачеркнула. Спорить с ней не планирую, частный случай не принципиален. Но как будут в такой ситуации оценивать эксперты на ОГЭ и ЕГЭ, хотелось бы знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от контекста и воли  автора. Если для Вас слова "на примере истории Ивана Ивановича" — пояснение, то ставьте запятые.

(1) Если Вы хотите передать смысл: "Вот как объяснил: использовал историю Ивана Ивановича как пример", — то ставьте запятые.
(2) Если Вы хотите передать смысл: "Вот так использовал историю Ивана Ивановича для объяснения", — то не ставьте запятых.

Comment: Спасибо! Учитель зачеркнул запятые при проверке... На что ссылаться?

Comment: Если это предложение было в контексте, то хотелось бы увидеть контекст, а если рассматривать его изолированно, то оба варианта имеют право на существование.

Comment: Это последний абзац сочинений по "После бала".

Comment: Вот так, на примере истории Ивана Васильевича, мастер слова Л.Н.Толстой показал читателю насколько сильно одно событие может повлиять на жизнь и судьбу человека

Comment: Материя эта очень тонкая. Опять не хватает контекста. По-моему, если в сочинении идет речь о том, что автор хотел объяснить свои взгляды и использовал для этого историю Ивана Ивановича, то подходит вариант с запятыми. А если просто излагается история Ивана Ивановича, а в конце оказывается,что на ее примере автор объяснил свои взгляды,  то без запятых.  У нас на сайте есть учителя; интересно, что они скажут.

Comment: Мне кажется, для простого  предложения без обособления  трудно подобрать интонацию. Как разделить его на две фразы восходящего и нисходящего тона? И нужны ли дополнительные произносительные паузы?

Comment: @Jasmin, О этот вечный вопрос о влиянии интонации на постановку запятых! Не считаю себя достаточно компетентным, чтобы спорить.

Comment: Интонация - вещь сложная и простая одновременно, и, читая текст, мы обычно не задумываемся о его интонационном решении, а просто читаем. Вот Вам удобно прочитать это предложения без обособления? Что-то вроде: Вот так на примере истории Ивана Ивановича (пауза) автор объяснил читателю свои взгляды. Это "вот так" как-то не соединяется в одну фразу (без паузы) с  последующим обстоятельством.

Comment: @Jasmin Я понимаю, воздуха не хватает дотянуть до такой паузы, а нужно. По мне так пусть автор пишет так, чтобы паузы соответствовали запятым, я запятые — смыслу, вместо того, чтобы ставить запятые лишь потому, что у читателя воздуха не хватает в легких.

Comment: А по мне текст должен читаться легко и свободно, даже если вы его видите  в первый раз, и совершенная фонетическая форма - его основное достоинство. Что касается смысла, то он в данном случае практически одинаков; о смысловых оттенках можно спорить, но читателю для понимания ситуации это мало что дает.

Comment: @Jasmin Я тоже считаю, что текст должен читаться легко и свободно. Об этом автор должен позаботиться заранее, естественные паузы должны соответствовать смыслу. А в данном случае разница очень маленькая, но есть. И естественная пауза падает не в лучшее место. Далее возникает вопрос: при постановке запятой отдать приоритет интонации или нюансам смысла? Вы отдали предпочтение первому, а школьный учитель (и я вместе с ним) — второму. И кто прав — не берусь судить.

Answer (score 0):

**Вот так, на примере истории Ивана Ивановича, автор объяснил читателю свои взгляды».**

Вообще говоря, выбор факультативный, поэтому рассмотрим **два варианта решения**  (с обособлением и без обособления)  и сравним их.

1) **Значение уточнения (как именно?)**

Обстоятельственный оборот обособляется, так как имеет **пояснительное значение** (раскрывает содержание указательного местоимения ***так***).

У Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

**Уточняющие обстоятельства образа действия:** Только **так**, среди травы, цветов, пшеницы, и могла начаться наша река Ворша (Сол.);  Вот **так**, походя, вопрос не решить.

**Какие факторы способствуют уточнению?**

а) **При наличии частиц** перед местоимением (***вот так, только так***) ударение падает на это сочетание, после него делается пауза, оборот обособляется.

б) если **сложно составить одну интонационную фразу** из местоимения  ***так*** и последующего распространенного обстоятельства, поэтому требуется пауза

Пример: **Так, с помощью этой своеобразной игры,** решала она обыкновенно свои житейские задачки. [Людмила Улицкая. Чужие дети (1998)]

**Вариант 2.  Нет значения уточнения**

**Какие факторы способствуют отсутствию  уточнения?**

Нет паузы, местоимение ***так*** близко по значению к частице, последующее обстоятельство обычно мало распространенное, единая фраза легко составляется, текст часто технический.

**Так с помощью простых приборов** удалось выяснить важные и глубоко скрытые тайны развития культурных растений. [Б. Зубков. Слышу, как трава растет // «Юный натуралист», 1975]

**Так с помощью автоматики** достигается наибольшая производительность и лучшее качество продукции. [В. И. Коваленков, А. В. Храмой. Автоматика и телемеханика // «Наука и жизнь», 1947]

Comment: Спасибо, учитель в сочинении запятые зачеркнула... К чему апеллировать?